# How can I edit the lightdm.conf file and save it?

Tags: permissions, sudo, etc

I was searching for login screens like mac and I got this one

[MAC OSX LOGIN SCREEN](https://github.com/Wattos/LightDM-Webkit-MacOSX-Theme)

I did everything correctly and suddenly I was told to edit

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

I opened the file in gedit and I changed it but I couldn't save it - I got the error "you do not have permission to edit this file". I saw from the permissions that only root has permission to edit it, so I ran

```
sudo su
```

which logged me in as root, but I was still not able to complete the edit.

How can I edit and save this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **gedit** or **nano** (among others) as below

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
sudo -H gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for gedit or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for name to save your edits.

Either will do fine, the only difference is that nano is a terminal-based editor while gedit has its own GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your `lightdm.conf` file with this command instead with your normal user (not root):

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and enter this code:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Enter your user password at the prompt.

Edit the file as needed and save it.