# Samba server not reading config file or config file incorrect

Tags: server, samba, file-sharing

Running ubuntu 16.04. desktop. Samba installed and client is working as expected. Ubuntu can access the windows machines. The problem is the samba server does not seem to be working. I used the info from this page https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/samba-file-server and followed the steps there to configure the samba server on ubuntu. I used this guide [How can I edit the lightdm.conf file and save it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438524/how-can-i-edit-the-lightdm-conf-file-and-save-it) and edited the smb.conf file. I used gedit to edit the conf file. I closed terminal and checked that the conf file had the edits I needed. I restart the server to make sure on startup everything was working and I would think that would have caused the smb.conf file to be read with the changes I made. Did not work. From windows I still can not access the share I configured in the smb.conf file. Would be gratefull for any help. From windows I get windows can not access and the name of the share I am trying to access.

```
testparm -s
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Processing section "[share]"
Loaded services file OK.
WARNING: The 'netbios name' is too long (max. 15 chars).

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    server role = standalone server
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    unix password sync = Yes
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    dns proxy = No
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    create mask = 0700
    printable = Yes
    browseable = No


[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[share]
    comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
    path = /media/david/Elements
    read only = No
    create mask = 0755
    guest ok = Yes
```

Comment: No one can help you without more information. Please edit your question and add the output of the following command: `testparm -s`

Comment: can not do that it says the result is over by 703 characters longer then can be added in a comment what part of the testparm output did you want to see?

Comment: Don't add it as a comment. Edit your original question and add it to that. Or ask your question in the Ubuntu Forum which has more options.

Comment: added output of testparm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
[share]
    comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
    path = /media/david/Elements
    read only = No
    create mask = 0755
    guest ok = Yes
```

To this:

```
[share]
    comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
    path = /media/david/Elements
    read only = No
    create mask = 0755
    guest ok = Yes
    force user = david
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

/media/david by design allows only david to get to the Elements folder. force user makes the "guest" network user appear to be "david" - at least for this share.

You have another problem with the host name of your machine which we can fix but see how far this gets you.

Comment: Very strange when I look at the shares from windows i c a share called Elements and a share called share. The share called Elements still gives same error BUT the share called share gives me access from windows to the Elements dir. Thank u that seems to solve the problem. Oh that is what the netbios error is it does not like the very long server name?

Comment: If you have a share named Elements I bet you created a samba share from your file manager. If you run `net usershare info --long` and get output you should "unshare" it from your file manager to eliminate any confusion. ... Samba uses the host name for the netbios name and that comes with rules like how long it can be. It doesn't appear to be an issue here so just ignore it. No need to fix something that ain't broke.

Comment: correct not broke never fix. since the share called share is doing what I wanted I will leave all as is. on the windows side I assigned a drive letter to the share dir and thats perfect for what I needed. now how do I give u rep for the soultion?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers